# jQuery sliding panel for multiple instances

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that works great, you can click one button which triggers one sliding div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('div.shareTab').on('click', function () {
    $('.sharePanel').animate({
        'width': 'show'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('.shareFade').fadeIn(100);
    });
});
$('.shareClose').on('click', function () {
    $('div.shareFade').fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('.sharePanel').animate({
            'width': 'hide'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
});
```

I have a different project which requires multiple buttons and multiple panels, is there a better way to write my script rather than just copy/pasting the script multiple times.

I have supplied a fiddle below to show what i'm trying to achieve, at the moment clicking on one of the names opens all the panels at once.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/e1szqj20/1/)

Comment: have you considered only using one panel and swapping content instead?

Comment: I'm open to better ways, unfortunately I am still in the process of learning jQuery with the help of Stack and other online resources so writing something like that I wouldn't know where to start but I would be happy just getting the current script tweaked, I have been messing round with ".each" but haven't succeeded in getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that using data attribute and some tricks on jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.shareTab").each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      $('.sharepanel' + $(item).data("panel")).animate({
        'width': 'show'
      }, 1000, function() {
        $('.sharepanel' + $(item).data("panel") + ' .shareFade').fadeIn(100);
      });
    });
  });

  $('.shareClose').on('click', function() {
    $('div.shareFade').fadeOut(100, function() {
      $('.sharePanel').animate({
        'width': 'hide'
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

This is fiddle fork:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ihab_mardoud/hgrn9bu5/1/)

Comment: Yeah I have seen a lot of data attributes being used, thanks for the help, that works perfect.

Comment: Using this I found a small glitch, when the panel is expanded and you click through the names you can't go back to a previous panel unless you close the panel, is it easy to implement a toggle so one closes and the next opens, thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty quick and dirty way to go about it: https://jsfiddle.net/e1szqj20/3/

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="shareTab" data-panel-open="#john_panel">John</a></li>
    <li><a class="shareTab" data-panel-open="#steve_panel">Steve</a></li>
    <li><a class="shareTab" data-panel-open="#bob_panel">Bob</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sharePanel" id="john_panel">
        <div class="shareFade">
            <span class="shareClose" data-close-panel="#john_panel">x</span>
            <div>John's Panel</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="sharePanel" id="steve_panel">
        <div class="shareFade">
            <span class="shareClose" data-close-panel="#steve_panel">x</span>
            <div>Steve's Panel</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="sharePanel" id="bob_panel">
        <div class="shareFade">
            <span class="shareClose" data-close-panel="#bob_panel">x</span>
            <div>Bob's Panel</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the revised jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.shareTab').on('click', function () {
        panel = $(this).attr('data-panel-open');
        $(panel).animate({
            'width': 'show'
        }, 1000, function () {
            $(panel +' .shareFade').fadeIn(100);
        });
    });
    $('.shareClose').on('click', function () {
        panel = $(this).attr('data-close-panel');
        $(panel+' .shareFade').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $(panel).animate({
                'width': 'hide'
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```